# What’s the full changelog for things which actually had been implemented by Constantinople?

Tags: hardforks, constantinople

It’s being said that the Constantinople hard fork is a minor one.
But as far I know, this is isn’t just a miner reduction fees. They are additional things which were implemented (like a special ꜱꜱᴛᴏʀᴇ case fee change [which was later reverted](https://medium.com/chainsecurity/constantinople-enables-new-reentrancy-attack-ace4088297d9)).

So what’s the full set of changes and functionalities implemented by this latest hard fork ?

Comment: @Ismael the question you are talking about is **about what was planned, and this question is what actually happened** which isn’t the same thing.

Comment: @Ismael yet, the question you’re referencing is still about what was planned. And not everything happened as planned since.

Comment: @Ismael perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1013.md

Included EIPs:

- [EIP 145](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-145): Bitwise shifting instructions in EVM
- [EIP 1014](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1014): Skinny CREATE2
- [EIP 1052](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1052): EXTCODEHASH Opcode
- [EIP 1234](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1234): Delay difficulty bomb, adjust block reward
- [EIP 1283](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1283): Net gas metering for SSTORE without dirty maps

Comment: May you detail the purpose of each change in your answer instead of just giving the links please ?

Comment: Each referred EIP has "Morivation" section.  Do you want me to copy them into the answer?

Comment: [This is rather a rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370).

Comment: OK, the question was what is full change set.  Full change set is listed in EIP-1013, so I gave a link to EIP-1013 and also copied the whole change list from EIP-1013 into the answer, thus obeying the rule.